# Ensuring N-MOS is in triode region (high side switching)

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, nmos

I'm confused as how to use the n-MOS as a high side switch. I understand that the Vgs should be higher than Vdd enough to drive the FET into triode region (whether by means of a charge pump or gate driver), but at the same time the Vds should be smaller than Vgs-Vgs(th). How do we ensure this last condition is met when switching non-linear loads (i.e. a digital IC)?

Is there's a rule of thumb as of how many times higher Vgs should be from Vth in order to ensure a n-MOSFET is in triode region (i.e. closed switch)?

Comment: Just look at the datasheet- The RDSon specs are usually given for different values of Vgs, and there are curves provided as well.

Comment: The MOSFET does not care about VSS, VCC etc. It wants the proper voltage and polarity to turn it on. The reference is the source and the gate needs to be maybe 5V to 15V above source to turn it on depending on the MOSFET.

Answer (score 0):

At the edge of the triode (i.e. resistive) region, VGS is VTH above the drain voltage. As VGS increases above this, the device becomes more and more like a simple resistor. There is no 'magic' threshold for this.